# Configurar virtual host no Ubuntu

Tags: virtualhost, deepin

Estou tentando configurar o virtual host no meu Deepin OS e nada que fiz funciona. Antes que marquem a pergunta como duplicada, todas as alternativas que eu vi aqui no fórum eu tentei e não tive sucesso, vi vários e vários vídeos no youtube e tbm não funciona. Atualmente meu virtualhost está assim

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@gymdoctor.dev
    ServerName gymdoctor.dev
    ServerAlias www.gymdoctor.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/gymdoctor.dev/public/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

já tentei também com as opções de directory e apontar para a pasta public do projeto em laravel e nada. Alguém sabe alguma maneira de resolver isso ou o problema está no SO que eu uso já que todos os tutoriais para Ubuntu eu tentei.

RESOLVIDO: eu estava utilizando meusite.dev para criar o vhost, troquei para meusite.test e funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Você editou qual arquivo exatamente do Apache? E em que pasta? A instalação do Apache foi via `apt-get` ou instalou algo independente do repositório oficial? Dê detalhes para que possamos saber o que fez e assim conseguir orienta-lo.

Comment: O apache foi instalado via apt-get. Os arquivos que eu editei foi na pasta /etc/apache3/sites-available/meusite.dev `<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName meusite.dev
 ServerAlias www.meusite.dev
 ServerAdmin webmaster@gymdoctor.dev
 DocumentRoot /var/www/gymdoctor/public
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>` e no /etc/hosts apenas acrescentei 127.0.0.1 meusite.dev

Comment: você adicionou no *hosts* o endereço `meusite.dev` para apontar para 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Sim, adicionei. No chrome não funciona e no firefox ele pega o index da pasta /var/www/html e não /var/www/meusite.dev/public

Comment: Felipe eu respondi

Answer (score 1):

Mude a extensão de:

```
/etc/apache3/sites-available/meusite.dev
```

Para `.conf`

```
/etc/apache3/sites-available/meusite.dev.conf
```

O mesmo para:

```
/etc/apache3/sites-available/gymdoctor.dev
```

Para `.conf`

```
/etc/apache3/sites-available/gymdoctor.dev.conf
```

---

### Notas extras:

As notas aqui são para futuros visitantes:

Não esqueça de adicionar no hosts, para isto edite o arquivo `/ect/hosts` (provavelmente requer `sudo`), um exemplo se tiver o `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Então deixe-o semelhante a isto:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   meusite.dev
```